# Disable the backlit keyboard on startup

Tags: keyboard, ventura

I recently updated to a beta version of macOS Ventura 13.3 (I didn't record the build number though), and now my backlit keyboard turns on when I boot up macOS, but turns off (and can be changed) after logging in. I have two accounts and neither of them have it on, nor has the second account been used for a while. There are also no other OSes installed on my mac. It is an M1 MBP and has never done this before on earlier versions of Ventura OR Monterey.

To try and solve this, I updated to the stable version of Ventura (13.3 22E252). The issue persists.

People have complained about this, but the other way around. They WANT the backlit keyboard to be on when they're not logged in, I do not; I have checked the following already:

- FileVault is on (I have it on already)
- Adjust keyboard brightness in low light (is off)
- Turn keyboard backlight off after inactivity (set to never)
- There is nothing about accessibility

It's not a major issue, but I'd rather not see my keyboard backlight turn on. I've used my keyboard too much to the point where the backlight reveals the amount of wear.

Answer (score 1):

Try [booting in safe mode](https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/mac-help/mh21245/mac) and turning off the backlight there by going to System Settings -> Keyboard -> Keyboard Brightness, sliding it 0, and turning off Auto Adjust Keyboard Brightness in low light

Comment: My mac is one of those where the F5/F6 keys are for dictation and do not disturb modes instead of increase/decreasing the backlit keyboard brightness. Also, when I log in through safe mode, the same thing happens & my backlit keyboard turns off after logging in. Can you clarify what you mean by "turning off the backlight there"?